# Getting an error every time I install something with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, 23.04

I used this command on ubuntu cinnamon 23.04

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

It gave me this output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:12.2.0-3ubuntu1).
gcc set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fortune-mod fortunes-min gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10 librecode0 python3-configobj
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up xtrx-dkms (0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2) ...
Removing old xtrx-0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2 DKMS files...
Module xtrx-0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2 for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

xtrx.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
depmod...
Deleting module xtrx-0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2 completely from the DKMS tree
.
Loading new xtrx-0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2 DKMS files...
Building for 6.2.0-20-generic 6.3.2-060302-generic
Building initial module for 6.2.0-20-generic
Done.

xtrx.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/
depmod...
Building initial module for 6.3.2-060302-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.3.2-060302-generic is not su
pported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.3.2-060302-generic (x86_6
4)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/make.log for more
 information.
dpkg: error processing package xtrx-dkms (--configure):
 installed xtrx-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xtrx-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Content of /var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/make.log

```
DKMS make.log for xtrx-0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2 for kernel 6.3.2-060302-generic (x86_64)
Mo 29 Mai 2023 12:56:35 CEST
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.3.2-060302-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-17ubuntu1) 12.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-17ubuntu1) 12.2.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/xtrx.o
/var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/xtrx.c: In function ‘xtrxfd_mmap’:
/var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/xtrx.c:1075:31: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
 1075 |                 vma->vm_flags |= VM_LOCKED;
      |                               ^~
/var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/xtrx.c:1090:31: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
 1090 |                 vma->vm_flags |= VM_IO;
      |                               ^~
/var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/xtrx.c:1115:31: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
 1115 |                 vma->vm_flags |= VM_LOCKED;
      |                               ^~
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: /var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/xtrx.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:2031: /var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.3.2-060302-generic'
```

Comment: What's the content of `/var/lib/dkms/xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2/build/make.log`?

Comment: Edited my original question

Answer (score 0):

Dou you need xtrx-dkms package? xtrx kernel module needs to be built for all kernels that you have installed. If you do not need it remove it with `apt remove xtrx-dkms`. Then you should be able to use apt.

According to the output, the package xtrx is successfully built for kernel 6.2.0-20, but it fails for kernel 6.3.2-060302. You could remove the module just for 6.3.2-060302, but I am not sure how would that work with next `apt upgrade`. You can try something like `dkms remove -m xtrx -k 6.3.2-060302-generic`. I have probably missed some details in the command. Try `dkms status` to see module's details.

Comment: `apt remove xtrx-dkms` worked for me, thank you for the help

Comment: @Longlost If this answer solved your problem, please click the check mark to indicate that.